# How do I hook getX with a model class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a user model class in Flutter which I'm using to parse user data.
It looks like this:

```
    class UserModel {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final String email;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return UserModel(
      id: doc['id'],
      email: doc['email'],
      username: doc['username'],
    );
  }
}
```

When user logs into the app, I'm getting data from firebase and parsing it using the factory method of the class and then I'm using it in pretty much all the screens in the app. Now I'm trying to make it observable using the "Get" library in flutter but I'm not able to use the .obs for some reason. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

You can make the user variable which holds the `UserModel` as following:

```
final user = Rxn<UserModel>();
```

And then assign new value or use the value as following:

```
user.value = UserModel(....); // assign new [UserModel] instance


Obx(()=> user.value....) // use user observable
```

Comment: looking this for 3 month. but found now. can you tell me does it will update  custom list  inside this object @S. M. JAHANGIR

Comment: Yes as soon as the list is inside the object everything will be updated.